# Refreshing form results without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is an explanation of my structure for a better understanding of what I am trying to do.

I have an initial form where you can select an item. After you submit the initial form you get a table with multiple rows and columns and also three buttons at the end. One of the buttons opens a modal window with another form where you can edit some values of the table.

When I am saving and closing the form I added a `window.parent.location.reload();` to refresh the parent page and show the new edits. Unfortunately this will ask me If I want to resubmit the form on the parent page and it can be annoying! I need a method to refresh the parent-form's results instead of the entire page without getting dialog boxes all the time. Also, chrome wipes out all the previous data from the parent form and just reload the parent page to its' initial state.

Initial Form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="surveyCategories.cfm" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="post" value="1">
            <select name="survey" class="span3">
                <option value="">Select a Survey to Edit</option>
                <cfloop query="surveys">
                <option value="#id#">#name#</option>
                </cfloop>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Results Table with the buttons: (This is the table I need to refresh after closing the modal)

```
     <form name="list" method="post" action="surveyCategories.cfm" > 
     <input type="hidden" name="listFormPost" value="1">
      <table class="table table-hover">  
      <tr>
        <th>Select</th><th>Survey Name</th><th>Category</th><th>Category Weight</th>
      </tr>


        <cfloop query="categories">
            <tr>
                <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="mark" value="#recID#"></td>
                <td>#name#</td>
                <td>#categoryname#</td>
                <td>#cweight#</td>
           </tr>    
        </cfloop>
       </table> 

<hr />

<div class="pull-left">
<a href="##addCategory" role="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal">Add Category</a>

<a href="##update" role="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal">Update</a>

<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick="dlte(mark); window.parent.location.reload();" >Delete</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Modal Window:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Update</h3>
    <div id="results"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
     <form name="update" action="updateSCpair.cfm" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="post2" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="surveyid" value="#categories.surveyid#" >

        <input type="text" value="#categories.name#" class="input-xlarge" disabled> <br />

        <select name="categories" onChange="handleCategoryChange();">
            <option value="" selected >Select a Category</option>
            <cfloop query="ratingCat">
              <option value="#ratingCat.categoryid#"  >#ratingCat.categoryName#</option>
            </cfloop>
        </select>
        <br />
        <input id="score"  name="score" class="span3" type="text"  required >

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" onClick="window.parent.location.reload();">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick="upd();" >Save changes</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are going to have to show a bit more code.

Comment: Sure, I can edit my post.

Comment: Did you trying using AJAX? Doing something like window.parent.someAjaxRefreshFunction. Your 'someAjaxRefreshFunction' would make an XMLHTTPRequest to the server and use the results to refresh the form without reloading the page.

Comment: No I haven't. I will try it now though. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could use method=get instead of post. Your data are not sensitive, right?

Comment: On which form though? The one inside the modal?

Comment: "If get method is used and if the page is refreshed it would not prompt before the request is submitted again." That's why I suggested get method.

Comment: Having that in mind, make your choice and see how it goes. I think you need this on the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use AJAX.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   <script>
     function showModal(){ /*code to show modal*/}
     function hideModel(){ /*code to hide modal*/}

     function updateParentForm(jsonObject){
       var parentFormNameInput = document.getElementById('parent_form_name');
       parentFormNameInput.value = jsonObject.name;
     }

     function submitForm() {
       var xmlhttp;
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
         // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       } else {
         // code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }

       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function readyStateChange(){
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
           // Lets assume you're responding back with a JSON string:
           // { "name": "submitted name" }
           var jsonObject = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
           updateParentForm(jsonObject);
           hideModal();
         }
       }
       xmlhttp.open("POST","submit.cfm",true);
       xmlhttp.send("name=" + document.getElementById('modal_name').value);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="myDiv"><h2>Let's submit a form!</h2></div>

  <!-- HERE IS OUR BUTTON TO DISPLAY THE MODAL -->
  <button type="button" onclick="showModal()">Show Modal Form</button>

  <!-- 
    Our modal HTML might look like this:
    <form>
      <input name="modal_name" id="modal_name" />
      <button type="button" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
    </form>
  -->

  <form>
    <input name="name" id="parent_form_name" />
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The submitForm method takes care of the cross browser compatibility.  The onreadystatechange event is fired multiple times during the life cycle of the response.

All you care about is the readyState of 4 and the status of 200.  Your submit.cfm responds with JSON in this example for easy parsing.

You send the name value using the xmlhttp.send method.  For more then one parameter join each parameter with & ie xmlhttp.send('name=bill&age=30').

Code borrowed from: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jesse. So my modal form will call this function and then the function will refresh the parent page's form right? I need the modal form to refresh the parent one after I submit it.

Comment: The page will not be refreshed at all.  In the if statement of the onreadystatechange method is where you can update any element on the page.  So for example, in the document.getElementById("submitted_name").innerHTML = jsonObject.name;, you simply need to add an id to the form input element under the modal and update it's value.  

Element: <input id="parent_form_name" />.

Code:

document.getElementById('parent_form_name').value = jsonObject.name;

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like.

`window.location = 'http://yourlocation';`

If this does not work then you can submit form via AJAX. Please see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) or if you are using jQuery then [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)